# Do I have to create a new TcpClient for each message I send?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I remain frustrated in my attempts to send multiple TCP messages.  I do not know what I have to do on the client side.  I've tried using a Socket object and a TcpClient object.  I can send one message with no problem.  But what do I have to do to send a second message?  Do I have to just discard the socket or TcpClient and create a new one?  I've never yet been able to to get a second message to work.

Here is my latest attempt with TcpClient.  It sends one message and displays the response successfully.  But when I put a breakpoint on the first statement inside the while loop and look at the client object before sending the second message, I see that the client's Connected property is false.  But on the next line, when I try to call Connect(), an exception is thrown claiming that the object is already connected.

Could somebody please explain what's going on, and what I have to do?

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        while (true)
        {

            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This message came from the client.");

            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5001);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.

            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = new Byte[1024];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            stream.Close();

            if (MessageBox.Show("Reply: " + responseData + "  Try again?", "Try again?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Put the `client.Connect()` outside the `while(true)` loop, you only need to connect once in the TCP protocol. Also put the initialization of the `stream` outside the loop, and the `stream.Close();` outside at the end of the loop. Then you can send and receive as many messages as you like.

Comment: First, if the server is closing the connection after each message you can't fixed that in the client.  You need to write an application layer on top of TCP to handle more than one message.  The server should respond to each message sent with an ack or equivalent so the client doesn't flood the server with messages.  Each message should have a know termination like following 1) ASCII : know character like '\n'. 2) ASCII or Binary : send bytes count at beginning of each message 3) ASCII or Binary : Each message (or message type) has a known length.

Comment: The server is not closing the connection.  My messages have a known length.  I have moved the Connect() call outside the loop, and I am leaving the stream open.  I am not flooding my server with messages; each message is sent in response to a button click.  

I will post my latest code, both server and client, in a new question, and put a link to it a new comment here.