# Why can't I use the TCP client to send two message? (continuation)

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp

This is a continuation of [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864391/do-i-have-to-create-a-new-tcpclient-for-each-message-i-send).  I am starting a new thread so that I can show the latest complete server and client code, including all of the suggestions I have received in that thread and on Reddit.

I am running under Windows 7 Pro.

I have a very simple TCP server written in Python.  It creates a socketserver object and waits for a message.  When one arrives, the server prints it to its console and sends a simple acknowledgement back through the same port.

The client sends a numbered message to the server, waits for an acknowledgement, and displays it.  It then asks the user if another message should be sent.

The first message is sent and acknowledged successfully.  On the client side, it appears that the second message is sent successfully; the call to the network stream's Write() method succeeds.  But when the Read() message is called to get the acknowledgement, an exception is thrown: "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

Here is the server code:

```
import json
import threading

import socketserver
import time

with open('CAPS_TWMS_config.json', 'rt') as c:
    caps_config = json.load(c)

# We are listening on this port and all defined IP addresses
# listenPort = 5001
listenPort = caps_config["listen_port"]

# Were to send the information to.
clientIPAddress = '127.0.0.1'   # socket.gethostbyname('client')
# clientPort = 12345
clientPort = caps_config["send_port"]

dsnName = caps_config["dsn_name"]

# Message sequence number
sequence_num = 1
exit_app = False

class ListenSocketHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, this_server):
        socketserver.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, this_server)
        self.timeout = 10

    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = self.request.recv(1024).decode()
            # print (str.format("dataString[21]: {0}; dataString[24:26]: {1}", data[21], data[24:26]))
            print ('ListenSocketHandler recv()-> "%s"' % data)
            print ('ListenSocketHandler recv().length-> "%d"' % len(data))

            if len(data) > 0:
                self.request.send("I got a message!".encode())
                return
        except Exception as value:
            print('ListenSocketHandler - %s' % str(value))

        return


class ListenServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    """
    The multi-threaded server that will spawn threads running the Socket Handler for each
    connection
    """
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        # Create the Server Handler for connections to this computer listening on all IP addresses,
        # change '' to 'x.x.x.x'  to listen on a specific IP network.  This class will listen for messages    # from CAPS.
        server = ListenServer(('', listenPort), ListenSocketHandler)
        ip, port = server.server_address

        # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
        # more thread for each request
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
        server_thread.setDaemon(True)
        server_thread.start()

        while not exit_app:
            time.sleep(1)

        print ('Out of main loop.')
        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()
    except Exception as value:
        print("Failed to do something: %s", str(value))
```

Here is the client code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    try
    {
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5001);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        int messageCount = 1;

        while (true)
        {                    
            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
            string message = string.Format("This is message {0}", messageCount++);
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);


            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.

            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = new Byte[1024];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 receivedCount = 0;
            int sleepCount = 0;
            while (receivedCount == 0)
            {                        
                receivedCount = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedCount);
                if (receivedCount == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(250);
                    if (sleepCount++ > 20)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Response timeout.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (MessageBox.Show("Reply: " + responseData + "  Try again?", "Try again?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to do something with TcpClient: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the server to know the end of one request and the beginning of the next one?

Comment: Also, before returning from the handler, try `self.request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)`

Comment: Check to see if you are getting to : client.Close();.  It is normal for TCP to get data with zero bytes in the message so received count could be zero where you would exit out of the while loop.  You need to receive until all the data is received.  So 1 of 3 methods are used 1) Ascii : Receive until known character is received like '\n' 2) Ascii or Binary : Add byte count to beginning of message and read until all bytes received. 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length messages.  Each message (or message type) have a know number of characters.

Comment: At this point, I do not care about identifying the end of one request and the beginning of the next.  I'll worry about that once I figure out how to keep the two ends of the connection talking.

Comment: I downloaded TCPView.  When I start the Python server, I see the port created in the LISTENING state .  When I start the client, the state of the port changes to ESTABLISHED.  After the first message is received and acked, the socket's state changes to FIN_WAIT2, and the counters show expected numbers.  When the second message is sent, the line in the TCPView display for my port momentarily flashes red.  If I don't blink, I can sometimes see the received packet count change to 2.  When the red is cleared, the port has reverted to LISTENING and the counters are cleared.

Comment: can you logs the value of the variable `receivedCount ` in you client side to see if all data is received? I think you should do a debug to your code in server and client side

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol there are no packets and untill you realise that you will not make this work. TCP is reliable, there is no need to ack a message either. The acking is already part of the design of TCP and is on byte level basis, using sequence numbers. There is not an ack for every byte, several bytes can be acked at once by acking a higher seq nmbr, it is an implicit ack of the lower sequence numbers too. Read more about TCP.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, every time when a new client is connected it is reading the data and acknowledges to client and handler is closed(i.e. return) immediately after the following statement

```
 self.request.send("I got a message!".encode())
                return
```

Hence the connection is closed.and further command from client is not sending. You can wait in a loop to receive and acknowledge.

Comment: I do not believe that this can be correct.  When the socketserver object is created, the ListenSocketHandler class is specified to handle incoming data.  When a message is received, the handle() method of the ListenSocketHandler class is called.  That method processes the message (by sending an ack) and returns.  The method is not designed to run in a loop forever, and returning from that method does not kill the connection.

Comment: Oh .. Is it so ? My understanding is default connection handler(ListenSocketHandler) will not do anything unless you implement something in handle() method. So your handle() will be called for every new connection connected from client not for the each message from the client. Here  is the simple echo tcp server  [link] (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-19-sect-2.html#pythonian-CHP-19-EX-5).

Comment: Did you checked by add loop ?